# PHP get image from byte[] out of a Database

Tags: php, database, image

I want to display an Image with a PHP-Script.
I get the image data out of a Database. The data is a byte[].
Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried this yet:

```
function GetImage($imageDataArray)
{
   $base64String = "";
   for($i = 0; $i < count($imageDataArray); $i++)
   {
       $string = trim(strtr(base64_encode($imageDataArray[$i]), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
       $base64String .= $string;
   }

   return 'data:image/png;base64,' . $base64String ;
}
```

And call it here:

```
echo '<img src="'.$im->GetImage($imageDataArray).'" alt="Picture" />';
```

But I don't get an result. The picture is not shown.

Comment: have a look on following

[base64 encoded images][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259967/sending-displaying-a-base64-encoded-image

Comment: @Ummar: I tried it like this (see my code). It doesn't fit.

Comment: are you setting content-type header to image/png? like `header("Content-Type: image/png");`

Comment: yes, I tried that. But still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might help You [`Imagick::readImageBlob`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimageblob.php)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't want to use external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of `base64_encode() && use urlencode() || rawurlencode()`

Comment: @Ummar: I think with urlencode() it doesn't run. I think, the base64_encode() is wrong, because I get a String like this: _data:image/png;base64,MTM3ODANzgNzEMTMMTAMjYMTAMAMAMAMTMNzMNzINjgODIMAMAMAMTI4MAMAMAMTI4OANgMAMAMAMTk1NjIOTcM..._  I tried the same in ASP.NET MVC. I didn't have any problems there and the base64 string is different.