# Base64 image doesn't show when using PHP

Tags: php, html, image

I need to display an image which is in Base64 format. When I build the img tag in PHP it doesn't show the image (just the defualt 'broken image' icon). When I view the page source and click on the Base64 data is shows the picture as expected. Also, if I copy and paste the page source and save it as an HTML file it displays as expected. I also tried a random image and that worked however as my image works from a .html file I assume it is OK and should work?

The .php code:

```
header('content-type: text/html');

...

echo "<html><head></head><body>";
echo "Name = $name<br/>";
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpg;base64,$photo\"/>";
echo "</body></html>";
```

The HTML from View Source:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>Name = Andrea Pilipczuk<br/>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAyADIAA...{too big to fit here].../9k="/>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

This didn't come up in View Source but digging around Chrome, I inspected the image element and found at the end was "9k=�������". Is this some kind of padding? When I edited the element to remove these the image showed up as expected.

The following code removes the random characters and displays the image correctly but seems a bit hacky, would obviously prefer to solve the underlying issue.

```
$unpadded = explode("=", $photo);
$padding = strlen($unpadded[0]) % 3;
$padded = $unpadded[0];
while ($padding > 0) {
  $padded .= "=";
  $padding--;
}
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,$padded\"/>";
```

Comment: If you modify to `image/jpeg` it makes a difference?

Comment: Can you post the image? for testing?

Comment: And the relevant HTML output would be helpful.

Comment: You might need a doctype as well, but it could be unrelated.

Comment: Try this post, it should have your answer;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259967/sending-displaying-a-base64-encoded-image

Comment: doctype has no effect. that link has content type as image however I also need text

Comment: Yes, I have found some suspect characters at the end of the data uri. See edited question

Comment: Where is the code that sets the $photo variable.

Comment: $photo is read from an encrypted file. Would the decryption process have anything to do with it? I have got it working by exploding at the '=' then manually adding the '='s back which get's rid of the '?in black diamond' characters