# FancyBox error when using PHP. Any ideas?

Tags: php, jquery, css, fancybox

just going to share my code and see if anyone can spot what's causing this.

The error reads:
"The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later."

**ShowAll.PHP:**

```
    <?
include_once "db.php";
session_start();
$gid=$_SESSION['gid'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,groupid FROM images where gid='".$gid."' and imagetype='1' ORDER BY id");
print(" <div id='wrapper'>  
        <!--start: Container -->
        <div class='container'>
        ");
        $j=0;
        print("     
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='span6'>
                <h1>My Gallery</h1>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class='span6'>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--start: Row -->
        <div class='row'>");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            if ($j==6){
                $j=0;
                print("</div>");
                        print("         
                <!--start: Row -->
                <div class='row'>");
                print("<div class='span2'>");
                print("<p><div class='picture'><a rel='image' href='largeimage.php?groupid=".$row['groupid']."'><img src='showimage.php?id=".$row['id']."'><div class='image-overlay-zoom'></div></a></div>");
                print("</div>");
                $j++;
            }else{
                print("<div class='span2'>");
                print("<p><div class='picture'><a rel='image' href='largeimage.php?groupid=".$row['groupid']."'><img src='showimage.php?id=".$row['id']."'><div class='image-overlay-zoom'></div></a></div>");
                print("</div>");
                $j++;
            }
        }
print("</div>");?>
```

**largeimage.php:**

```
<?php

$groupid=$_GET['groupid'];


print("             <img src='showimagelarge.php?groupid=".$groupid."'>");

?>
```

**showimagelarge.php:**

```
include_once "db.php";

session_start();



$gid=$_SESSION['gid'];

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$query = "SELECT image from images where groupid=". intval($_GET["groupid"])." and gid='".$gid."' and imagetype='2'";

$rs = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));

echo base64_decode($rs["image"]);

?>
```

**showimage.php:**

```
include_once "db.php";

session_start();



$gid=$_SESSION['gid'];

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$query = "SELECT image from images where id=". intval($_GET["id"])." and gid='".$gid."'";

$rs = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));

echo base64_decode($rs["image"]);

?>
```

Comment: Where is your fancybox initialization code?

Comment: If you're still in develop process you should try to avoid the use of mysql_* since it will be deprecated soon. search google for "php prepared statments"

Comment: I have a header with the CSS and a footer with the JS being called through an include.

Got'cha, Pluda. Just trying to get it to work then I can optimize it to be much better.

Comment: Your browser only show this message "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later." ? I guess that you have a syntax error in somewhere.

Comment: Is this a JS or PHP error? Which file are you calling, when retrieving this error? Have you checked your server error log's? You should provide more explanation's to your question and reduce the code to the file that is affected.

Comment: Here's what is displaying, @Daniloisr:
http://i.imgur.com/Utdgj.png

Comment: The thing is, before I put the Fancybox in place, it was pulling and displaying images just fine via the ahref, but once I added all of the fancybox classes and such to the links, it blew up. Trying to figure out why. :(

Comment: Yeah, they're returning the images just fine. You can see here: http://i.imgur.com/1sD8J.png

The images are being returned, but when it comes to clicking them to display the enlarged versions, after I've added fancybox it just doesn't work.

Comment: So your problem is in `showimagelarge.php`, you know how to see server logs to find the problem?

Comment: @daniloisr , I'm not sure. Where would those be located?

Comment: It depend of what OS you are using, search on google for `where php error_log OS_NAME`, [example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/error_log-defines-file-where-script-errors-logged/)

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure if I can do that. I'm using a host called Bounceweb that has a control panel called the cPanel. Is there a way I can do it in there?

Comment: I found a error_logs file on the FTP. But nothing in it references showimagelarge.php at all.

Answer (score 3):

You are rendering the link to your images this way :

```
<div class='picture'><a rel='image' href='largeimage.php?groupid=".$row['groupid']."'>....
```

... so your link `href` will not have any image extension (jpg, png, gif). Because that fancybox doesn't know what `type` of content to handle, hence the message

```
The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.
```

You need to force the `type` of content to `image` within your fancybox custom script. That is documented here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support, FAQ tab No. 5

You can do either:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".picture a").fancybox({
      "type": "image"
    });
  });
</script>
```

... or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[rel="image"]').fancybox({
      "type": "image"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Oh interesting. Where do I actually place those two lines? In one of the PHP files, or my fancybox.js file, or the fancybox.css file? 

Not completely sure where it needs to be stuck at is my problem :(

Comment: @JamesAnderson : in the same file that you are loading jQuery and fancybox js and css files, I bet is ShowAll.PHP

Comment: @JamesAnderson : I edited my answer. The complete piece of code that should be in your `<head>` section AFTER you loaded jQuery and fancybox js and css files

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'll try it out!

Comment: @JamesAnderson ... see my previous comment and edited answer ;)

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to do much of anything. :(

Comment: can you share a link? ... at the end of the road what it matters to fancybox is the rendered html and the correct initialization of the script.

Comment: Sure! http://ravingtechguy.com/weddingpics/login.php

Since everything is test, you can just login with my 2nd dummy account:
ID: Silvashadows@msn.com
pw: amleo241

After logging in, you'll want to go to "My Gallery" under "My Account".

Comment: don't you think this `base64_decode` is creating the issue? why not just echo the image as simple `<img />`? ... check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3260011/1055987 for reference.

Comment: Not sure honestly. I'm still able to do an inspect element on the page in Chrome, and see all of the images just fine - large and small versions, so the PHP is definitely calling the images. It's just, how do I populate them into the fancybox?

Comment: Actually, I think that's what we're doing like this:
In showimagelarge.php, we're doing the base64_decode, then in largeimage.php, it's being placed into an <img src> So basically, the same thing, right?

Comment: Anyone have any other ideas?