# PHP receive http post request as $_POST

Tags: php, android, post, http-post

I am trying to receive some image data in php using $_POST if I am trying to post small string like "abc" I am getting the response but when I try to post huge data like 108 KB it's not showing the response might be I need to increase some limit but I don't have access in php.ini file.

is there any other way?

And I am posting the data from android so is there any string shorten encoding in android and decoding in php available. I already used base64 to get the image data.

My php code to echo the return.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');


if(isset($_POST['incidentDetails']))
{
    echo 'Responce from server:  ' . $_POST['incidentDetails'];
}
else
{
    echo 'Request without paramenter';  
}
?>
```

The url - http://bumba27.byethost16.com/incidentManagments/api/adding_incident_details.php

I need to post as parameter name incidentDetails- http://www.filedropper.com/log_2

[image]

Android Code

```
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://bumba27.byethost16.com/incidentManagments/api/adding_incident_details.php");

        try 
        {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("incidentDetails", headerData));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } 
        catch (Throwable t ) 
        {
            Log.d("Error Time of Login",t+"");
        }
```

Comment: if you are dealing with image files why are you using $_POST instead of using $_POST use $_FILES

Comment: no it's is base64 converted image. Actually there will be many image and along with the image I need to pass other parameter also that why I need to pass as base64

Comment: Even if you have many images and many parameters there is no need to base64 encode images.

Comment: `it's not showing the response` . No? Nothing? Where do you display the response? Why are you asking for string shortening code where base64 increases payload with 30℅ ?

Comment: Updated my question with url and parameter

Comment: We cannot see that you posted a base64 encoded image. Only a image url. We cannot see the response. You did not answer my questions. You did not tell why you want images to be base64 encoded. You did not tell you would post json.

Comment: I am sending this from android device android android code is already ready from android it is posting base64 I can't modify that and yes I from android side I am getting all parameter as json.

for that posted base64 image please download this file .http://www.filedropper.com/log_2   You can see full thing that I am trying to pass

Comment: `I am getting all parameter as json. ` ??? You mean: i send all parameters including the images as json text?

Comment: Yes I send all parameters including the images as json

Comment: My god you should have stated that as first line in your post right away.  You are just trying to send json text. Now you spilled our time. And still you did not answer my comment on `its not showing the response`.

Comment: As per my php code you can see I put echo. so it should say 'Responce from server:  bla bla bla 
but now I getting complete blank nothing is there but if I post "abc" instead of that json I am getting 'Responce from server:  abc'

That mean due to big json value I am facing some problem from php server side I think so ....

any suggestion ...
and am really sorry not to explain properly..

Comment: If you are getting nothing  than it times out ? Is nothing/blank not even 'Response from server:  ' ? Post your android code please.

Comment: Why did you not state on the first line that you want to receive a big json text? Come to the point please. You dont have to talk about images and base64.

Comment: not getting your point

Answer (score 1):

Are you making sure you have enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag on the HTML form sending the image data?

```
<form name="someform" id="someform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="somefile.php">
```

**EDIT:**
According to the PHP.NET website, you have to do a process to save files - not just print out the $_POST array:

```
$name= $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
$type= $_FILES["myfile"]["type"];
$size= $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
$temp= $_FILES["myfile"]["temp_name"];
$error= $_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

if ($error > 0)
    die("Error uploading file! code $error.");
else
   {
    if($type=="image/png" || $size > 2000000)//condition for the file
    {
    die("Format  not allowed or file size too big!");
    }
    else
    {
     move_uploaded_file($temp, "uploaded/" .$name);
     echo "Upload complete!"; 
     }
}
```

Comment: I am only getting result on application/x-www-form-urlencoded

You can also try - http://bumba27.byethost16.com/incidentManagments/api/adding_incident_details.php

Parameter- incidentDetails

Comment: I just sent Desert.jpg (stock Windows background image) via a form using application/x-www-form-urlencoded - did you get anything?

Comment: I am not saving any thing in data base primarily just doing echo the result

Comment: You can use Advanced Rest Client to check the response I have updated my question also.

Comment: I can't upload the image like this in that case I need to change the android code also. I need to post it as Base64

I have attached the url as well as parameter also.. Please if you don't mind can you check that..

Comment: Did you look at this SO Q&A?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259967/sending-displaying-a-base64-encoded-image

Comment: Yes @NYCBilly I am doing base64_encode from android side and sending to php server problem is php server can't receive it due to big parameter value. Check the parameter file I had added as .text in my question.