# How does the <img>-tag work in Chrome?

Tags: html, browser

I'm curious about how the `<img>`-tag works.

I can set an URI as `src`, like:

```
<img src="./logo.jpg"/>
```

I can also set a API url, like:

```
<img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/449?v=3"/>
```

In my understanding, the `<img>`-tag will init a get call with the url specified in `src` and render the jpeg binary returned. But could anyone confirm if the second one return a binanry string or a dataurlstring (like base64 encoded), I am wondering how the browser know what kind of data string it gets?

Thanks

Comment: I don't haver any source, but I guess Chrome hints the content-type and sets it finally with the actual MIME type received from the server. At least Firefox is doing it like that.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Thanks, I am wondering how the browser know if the return data string is binanry data or base64 encoded data string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server sends a `Content-type` header with every response that tells the browser what to expect.

For example, an image might have a Content-type of image/jpeg.

More details at [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) or [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)

The content itself may be binary, or encoded in some way (commonly base 64). The encoding used is also passed as a header.

Comment: Thanks, so the response let the browser know what kind of resource is returned. But I wondering how do I know if the server return the binary of jpeg or a base64 encoded dataURL string? When I print what I get from that URL in console, it is just some unreadable character.

Comment: You don't need to.  Content-type tells the browser the file type. The file type image/jpeg, for instance, means an binary image compressed.  If it is encoded the content-type would be (I believe) `image/jpeg;base64` - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259967/sending-displaying-a-base64-encoded-image for more imformation.

Comment: I'm not sure that most browsers do read base64 images except inline. Moreover, if you have choice to send binary or base64, why would send anything but binary? Binary is smaller and doesn't require the client to do transformations before uncompromising and rendering the image.

Comment: OP is asking how the browser knows what it's getting. The mechanism exists even if it's not widely used today. There was a time when 8-bit binary transfers weren't always supported over dial--up lines.

Comment: @J.A.Streich Right now, I am reading the jpeg logo from github API, and I want to know what is returned from that url

Comment: @Kuan binary is returned from that address. -- It has content/type of image/jpeg, and returns bytes that don't exist in the base64 space.

Comment: @J.A.Streich thanks, once I got this file, how can I turn it into a dataURL string( a HEX string to represent the binary data), so that I can just give it to other image as src rather than giving them the same URL and do another request for this image?

Comment: @kuan you have strayed off point. You're asking a different question now, so post a new question if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

In the avatar url without the `JPG` extension, they have created custom rewrite rules which removes the extension from the URL path.