# display byte format jpeg in img

Tags: python, html

I have a byte format jpeg that I get from python that looks like this `b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\...'`. How can I display that inside an HTML `img` tag? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the bytes to base64, then use the native HTML b64 format for your image:

```
from base64 import b64encode

bytez = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01'
b64_encoded = b64encode(bytez).decode()
print(b64_encoded)
>>> '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ=='
```

and then:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ==" alt="Your image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:
write it to a file and have the HTML refer to it.

```
        b = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\...'
        with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(b)
```

In the HTML document:

```
        <img src="image.jpg">
```

---

Hairier answer:
[base64 encode it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3260044/8431111),
using `data:image/jpeg;base64`.